# WooCommerce: вывод id товара по произвольному полю

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Может, кто сталкивался. Мне надо вывести все id товара, у которых значение произвольного поля равны определенному значению.

Например есть 5 товаров из 50, у которых есть произвольное поле type и его значение 1.

Вот мне надо вывести все id этих 5 товаров у которых type=1.

Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Product это post_type соответственно вы можете использовать WP_Query для выборки:

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'   => 'type',
            'value' => '1',
        ],
    ],
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts ) :
        $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```